# PHP unicode char face convert to hex for Arabic

Tags: javascript, php, dom, arabic, unicode-string

I am experiencing a problem in converting Arabic chars to hex values

```
  $text = "يي";
  $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
  $text = preg_replace('~^(&([a-zA-Z0-9]);)~',htmlentities('${1}'),$text);
```

Result :

```
&#1610;&#1610;
```

Actually both chars are ي but in display it is changing faces according to char position first, middle , end , I want to get code as 
//ﻳ == ي

```
            'beginning'     =>   '&#xFEF3;',
            'middle'        =>   '&#xFEF4;',
            'end'           =>   '&#xFEF2;',
            'isolated'      =>   '&#xFEF1;'
```

I need char values as face on screen in html, JavaScript or in PHP.

Comment: why you want them shaped?

Comment: imagettftext is not rendering shapes intelligently and prints separate characters.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the shaping for `imagettftext`, you can use the library [ar-php](http://www.ar-php.org/project-php-arabic.html):

```
  require('../I18N/Arabic.php'); 
  $Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Glyphs');   
  $text = 'بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم'; 
  $text = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text);     
  imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 200, 
          100, $black, $font, $text);
```

Full sample:

```
<?php 
  // Set the content-type 
  header("Content-type: image/png"); 

  // Create the image 
  $im = @imagecreatefromgif('GD/bg.gif'); 

  // Create some colors 
  $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 
  $blue  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

  // Replace by your own font  
  // full path and name 
  $local = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; 
  $pos   = strrpos($script, '/'); 
  $path  = substr($script, 0, $pos); 
  $font  = $path.'/GD/ae_AlHor.ttf'; 

  // UTF-8 charset 
  $text = 'بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم'; 

  imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 
               50, $blue, $font, 'UTF-8:'); 

  imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 200, 
               50, $black, $font, $text); 

  require('../I18N/Arabic.php'); 
  $Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Glyphs'); 

  $text = 'بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم'; 
  $text = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text); 

  imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 
          100, $blue, $font, 'ArGlyphs:'); 

  imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 200, 
          100, $black, $font, $text); 

  // Using imagepng() results in clearer  
  // text compared with imagejpeg() 
  imagepng($im); 
  imagedestroy($im); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , I already crossed with this and another for Persian language but my language is not matching with this class, I know I can alter the char table but with to get grammatically then this heck.